# How to retry on 5XX errors using Apache Http Client library

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache http client and I am using my custom `HttpRequestRetryHandler`. Code for that given below.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyCustomHttpRequestRetryHandler implements HttpRequestRetryHandler {
    private final String serviceName;
    private final int maxRetries;

    private static final List<Class> RETRYABLE_EXCEPTIONS = Arrays.asList(
        InterruptedIOException.class, // ConnectTimeoutException, ConnectionPoolTimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException and RequestAbortedException
        NoHttpResponseException.class, // Usually when under heavy load, the web server receive requests but fails to process them
        ConnectException.class // Occurs when socket connection fails to to a remote address and port

    );

    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
        if (executionCount > maxRetries) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isExceptionRetryable(exception)) {
            log.warn("Service: {}: Re-trying service call due to : {}. Number of retry: {}/{}", serviceName, exception.getMessage(), executionCount,
                maxRetries, exception);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isExceptionRetryable(Throwable throwable) {
        for (Class clazz : RETRYABLE_EXCEPTIONS) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(throwable)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this retryable exception list, I can very well capture Timeout and connectivity exceptions, but how to handle retrying on 5XX error?
Based on exception handling documentation, https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html, I was not able to find the Exception when 5XX is returned.

Any help us appreciated!

Note:- Dependency version

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can very well right a dirty logic to manually retry on 5XX, but I want to see is there any Apache http client provides out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question too soon. I found below solution for my question.

```
/**
 * This class will define retry strategy for service unavailable errors
 */
@Slf4j
public class ServiceUnavailableRetryHandler implements ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy {
    private final Set<Integer> retryableErrorCodes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(500, 503));
    private final long retryInternal = 500;
    private final int maxRetries = 3;


    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(HttpResponse response, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        String errMsg = String.format("Service Unavailable - StatusCode: %d, Attempt#: %d/%d", statusCode, executionCount, maxRetries);

        if (executionCount > maxRetries) {
            log.error(errMsg);
            return false;
        }

        if (retryableErrorCodes.contains(statusCode)) {
            log.warn(errMsg);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public long getRetryInterval() {
        return this.retryInternal;
    }
}
```

Add add this handler/strategy class into your http client builder.

```
httpClientBuilder.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryHandler());
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy, but no need to create a custom retry handler

```
httpClientBuilder.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(maxRetires, retryInterval))
```

Comment: This is wrong. DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy retries only for `503` codes